# Form failing validation submits anyway

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So I am trying to re-learn web design as part of an app I am creating right now.  And for some reason when I click the submit button on my form, it is still submitting even though the validation fails.  I can see the JavaScript prints the error message to the result label, but a second later it loads the PHP page anyways.  I am unsure why this is happening.  Yes I know that in my JS file everything returns false, but that is to demonstrate that I can fail the validation and have it submit anyways which makes no sense.  Any help is appreciated, thank you!

**register.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/validate_registration.js"></script>
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>Family Polaris</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="registrationForm" action="register.php" onsubmit="validateForm()" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="title"><h1>Family Polaris</h1></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerColumn"><h2>Registration</h2></td>
                    <td class="rightColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerColumn">
                        <p>Thank you for taking the time to consider Family Polaris for your family needs!
                        <br>In order to get started all new users must register before they can login.
                        <br>Please fill out the registration form below, thank you!<br><br>
                        <span class="required">Fields marked with an asterisk (*) are required fields.</span><br><br></p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftColumn">First Name&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerColumn">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" maxlength="50" required /><span class="required">&nbsp;*</span></td>
                    <td class="rightColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftColumn">Last Name&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerColumn">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" maxlength="50" required /><span class="required">&nbsp;*</span></td>
                    <td class="rightColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftColumn">E-Mail&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerColumn">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="50" required /><span class="required">&nbsp;*</span></td>
                    <td class="rightColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftColumn">Password&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerColumn">&nbsp;<input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="20" required /><span class="required">&nbsp;*</span></td>
                    <td class="rightColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftColumn">Confirm Password&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerColumn">&nbsp;<input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" maxlength="20" required /><span class="required">&nbsp;*</span></td>
                    <td class="rightColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftColumn">4-digit Pin Code&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerColumn">&nbsp;<input type="password" name="pin" id="pin" pattern="[0-9]{4}" required /><span class="required">&nbsp;*</span></td>
                    <td class="rightColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftColumn">Confirm Pin Code&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerColumn">&nbsp;<input type="password" name="confirmPin" id="confirmPin" pattern="[0-9]{4}" required /><span class="required">&nbsp;*</span></td>
                    <td class="rightColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerColumn"><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" onClick="printErr('')" />&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="Submit" /></td>
                    <td class="rightColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="leftColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerColumn"><br><span id="result"></span></td>
                    <td class="rightColumn">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**validate_registration.js**

```
function validateForm() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirmPassword").value;
    var pin = document.getElementById("pin").value;
    var confirmPin = document.getElementById("confirmPin").value;

    if(pass.length < 8) {
        printErr("Error: Passwords must be between 8 and 20 characters in length.");
        return false;
    } else if(isNaN(pin)) {
        printErr("Error: Pin code must be numeric characters only.");
        return false;
    } else if(pass != confirmPassword) {
        printErr("Error: Passwords do not match.");
        return false;
    } else if(pin != confirmPin) {
        printErr("Error: Pin codes do not match.");
        return false;
    } else {
        printErr("");
        // DO AJAX STUFF
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}

function printErr(errMsg) {
    var div = document.getElementById('result');
    div.innerHTML = errMsg.toString();
}
```

**register.php**

```
<?php
    include "conn.php";

    echo "<br>First Name: " . $_POST['firstName'];
    echo "<br>Last Name: " . $_POST['lastName'];
    echo "<br>E-Mail: " . $_POST['email'];
    echo "<br>Password: " . $_POST['password'];
    echo "<br>Pin: " . $_POST['pin'];

    if(empty($_POST['firstName']) || empty($_POST['lastName']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['pin']))
    {
        echo "<br>Error: Please fill out all required fields.";
    } else if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirmPassword']) {
        echo "<br>Error: Passwords do not match.";
    } else if($_POST['pin'] != $_POST['confirmPin']) {
        echo "<br>Error: Pin codes do not match.";
    } else if(strlen($_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 8) {
        echo "<br>Error: Passwords must be between 8 and 20 characters in length.";
    } else if(strlen($_POST['pin']) != 4) {
        echo "<br>Error: Pin codes must be a maximum of 4 characters.";
    } else if(strlen($_POST['firstName']) > 50 && strlen($_POST['lastName']) > 50 && strlen($_POST['email']) > 50) {
        echo "<br>Error: First Name, Last Name, and E-mail fields must be shorter than 50 characters in length.";
    } else if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<br>Error: You must use a valid e-mail address.";
    } else {
        echo "<br><br>Successfully checked all data!";
        /* NOT YET IMPLEMENTED -- IGNORE
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO family (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":username", $_POST['username']);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password", $_POST['password']);
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            echo "Data added successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to add data";
        }*/
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try changing onsubmit method like this

```
onsubmit="return validateForm()"
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!  Such a simple thing to miss!

Comment: Thank you Jeremy Voss. I just wonder why someone downvoted my answer